# Java error compiler with multiple persistence-units

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Netbeans 14 with java 8 or 17.

With a single persistent-unit using the Users.java and UsersJpaController.java classes to access a single table Users, everything works fine.

When I configure a second persistence-unit to access another database,
I get this error (without adding code or creating tables; only add persistence-unit)

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
(default-compile) on project management: 
Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException:
javax.annotation.processing.FilerException:
**Attempt to recreate a file for type it.lsc.management.db.Users_**
-> [Help 1]
```

I need to connect to some databases at the same time. Do you have any suggestions to solve the problem?

The file persistence.xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="db_management" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.25\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=CRM_LSC;encrypt=false"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="uuu"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="uuu!"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="db_agen" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.195\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=db_agen"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="uu"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="uuu!"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Issue seems to be that you have a plug-in to generate the meta model classes, and that you have all entities in both persistence units so User_ and others are generated twice. Configure the plugin to run on one persistence unit, or specify the classes that belong in the two (by specifying exclude unlisted classes then explicitly adding a class entry in the persistence.xml def for each) in a way that prevents overlap.

Comment: Many thanks, Chris
I i have removed this dependency from pom.xml
and everything works fine
Thank you!


<!--dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.10</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency-->